# Proving a result related to $100^{th}$ roots of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If we take the $100^{th}$ roots of unity ie. all complex roots of the equation $z^{100}-1=0$ and denote them as $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{100}$ then we are required to prove that $$\alpha_{1}^r+\alpha_{2}^r+...+\alpha_{100}^r=0$$ for $r\neq100k$ where $k$ is an integer.

I tried using the Euler form by denoting $$\alpha_{t}=e^{\frac{i2t\pi}{100}}$$ and trying to evaluate it as a GP but it was pretty lengthy and I couldn't simplify it out to zero so now I am confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: multiply the sum by $\alpha_1^r$ and observe that it doesn't change

Comment: Hint;  Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $100^{th}$ root of unity.  Then $\{\zeta\, \alpha_i\}$ is a permutation of the $\{\alpha_i\}$.  If $S$ denotes the sum then deduce that $\zeta^rS=S$ and finish from there.

Comment: @lulu Sorry but I'm not familiar with that kind of notation. What does {${\alpha_{i}}$} signify? And what do you mean by permutation in this context?

Comment: $\{\alpha_i\}=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_{100}\}$ is an ordered set with $100$ elements. a permutation just means the same set in a (possibly) different order.

Comment: @lulu OK and what does $\zeta^rS$ mean?

Comment: It means $\zeta^r$ times $S$.

Comment: @lulu Just to be clear $\zeta$ can be any of the above mentioned $\alpha_{i}$ values right?

Comment: Well, you want it to be primitive because you want $\zeta^r\neq 1$.

Comment: @lulu Yes I got it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the roots of $$z^n-1=0$$ are $$a_k=e^{2i\pi k/n},0\le k<n$$

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}a_k^r=a_0\dfrac{a_1^{nr}-1}{a_1^r-1}=0$$
if $n\nmid r$

Comment: Accepted this because it revealed where I went wrong in my attempt to solve it as a GP but other answers were good too.

Answer (score 2):

**A non-classical approach:**
We know, $z^{100}-1=0$ will have it's sum of roots as $0$ (using Vieta's theorem; $\frac{-b}{a}$)

So, we know that $$\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 ...+\alpha_{100}=0$$

Another point to note is, $\alpha^r$ will have the same modulus as $\alpha$ which is $1$, but the angle in the complex plane will be $r$ times as it was before.

So, applying this here, we can be confident to say that,
$${\alpha_1}^r + {\alpha_2}^r ...+{\alpha_{100}}^r=0$$

where $r$ is not an integral multiple of $100$.

For a simplified case of how this works, a graph is attached

```
Number of roots=5
```

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hgdiophi2c

Since $$\alpha_{t}=e^{\frac{i2t\pi}{100}}$$
$${\alpha_{t}}^{100k}=e^{{i2t\pi}k}=1$$

And each of ${\alpha_i}^r$ will jump to ${\alpha_{ir}}$ as can be seen from the graph or proved as per convenience. $\alpha_{ir}$ can be reduced recursively by reducing $ir$ by 100, i.e. $ir-100$, sometimes the value will be coincident but would always add up to 0.

```
For 100 roots, you can observe that the vertices do not change except when r=50 , 40 etc.
```

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rbi5ybugm1
(Don't miss this graph, it's worth it)

---

**Why are we certain that it will work?**

**1.Whenever $G.C.D(r,100)>1$ we will loose some vertices, Why?**

This is because ${\alpha_{t}}^r=e^{\frac{i2t\pi r}{100}}$ would reduce to roots of unity of some lower power.

**2.What happens when $G.C.D(r,100)=1$?**

Converse to the previous statement, the roots no longer roots of unity of some lower power. Hence the vertices are retained. If unsatisfied (consider $a$ as $\alpha$) using modulus
$\left[a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...,a_{[\frac{100}r]+1,...}\right]$ when raised to the power $r$
would shift to $\left[{a_{r},a_{2r},...,a_{r-1}...}\right]$ and the same manipulation can be
done for $a_{[\frac{100}{r^2}]+1,...}$ if applicable. (in this case, it would change to ${a_{r-2}}$ )

*here square brackets denote the greatest integer function*

One can *rigorously* prove that the Argand plane method provides a visual solution by iterating the mentioned points 1. and 2. for different lower powered roots of unity

Comment: So it's just rotating their positions on the unit circle?

Comment: What if $r=50$?  I'm not feeling as confident as you.  Your argument doesn't account for the fact that this won't work if $r=100$.

Comment: @B.Goddard I am sorry, i forgot to include the condition for r, i always had it in mind but just slipped, I'll just

Comment: @infinite-blank- yes, you can say so, try visualizing for 5 or 7 roots, and r = 2,3 you'll see

Comment: @infinite-blank- you can check the link provided

Comment: The problem is that your solution gives no reason why $r=50$ works and $r=100$ doesn't.  If $r=100$, then all of your angles coincide and the sum is not $0$.  How do we know that some smaller value of $r$ doesn't cause something similar?

Comment: @infinite-blank- I have added for 100 roots as well

Comment: I only see that you haven't proven anything yet.  Sure these angles jump around.  But how do you know they don't jump on top of each other, or in some other way find a configuration that doesn't add up to zero?  What happens when $r=50$, I ask again.

Comment: @B.Goddard Isn't ${\alpha_i}^r$ congruent to ${\alpha_ir}$ enough for the said proof? Each of $\alpha_i$ when $i=0(mod 2)$ lands on 1, while $i=1(mod 2)$ on $\alpha_{50}=-1$

Comment: But then what happens of $r=5$.  You haven't given a reason why these numbers always sort themselves out in an equally-spaced fashion so that they add to zero. We're just supposed to be "confident", even though when $r=100$, for it suddenly doesn't work.  WHY DOES IT WORK FOR $r=50$ and not $r=100$?  Until you address that, you have no proof

Comment: It's not trivial and it's still not proven.  All you did was restate the result.  Again.

Comment: Proofs tell why. You're telling what. You don't have a proof.

Comment: @B.Goddard give me a 'why' that cannot be answered. first of all, it was you who started a question thread right here, when the OP intended to ask for any possible help.

Comment: Since you can't answer it, I already have. If your intuition can be made into a sensible argument, then do it.  What happens if $r=4$ or $5$ or $85$?

Comment: @B.Goddard do you not follow what i write....i have included the poorly formatted GCD case just to justify the intuitive method, GCD(4,100)  will get you 4, and you'll get all roots of unity for 25... GCD(85,100) will give you 20 roots and so on reducing till GCD(a,b) =1, which will then tell the roots retained position in a specific configuration for the $b^{th}$ root of unity

Comment: gcd(4,100)=25* not 4

Comment: I understand what you're writing.  The problem is that you're writing has nothing of substance in it.  You keep saying "this will happen."  You never say why.  Your post has no merit.

Answer (score 1):

In general we have that

$$z^{n}-1=0 \iff (z-1)(1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1})=0$$

the for any $z\neq 1$

$$1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1}=0$$

and using $z=\alpha_1=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ we obtain

$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\ldots+\alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_{n}=0$$

and since $\alpha_1^{100k+r}=\alpha_1^r$ we obtain the result.